# Saving text from a textarea in a file

Tags: php, html, file, session

I am currently making a bio section for a website and so far I have a way to "edit the profile". What I want to happen is the text that is inserted be saved into a file I have already created. Here's the current code that I have with their according names.

Profile Editing Page (editprofile.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: login.php');
    }

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: login.php");
    }
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$file = "extra/" . $username . ".png";
if (!file_exists($file))
    $file = 'extra/defaultProfile.png';
?>
<html>
<title> Home Page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
          <li><a href="chat.php">Chat</a></li>
          <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="logout"><a href="index.php?logout='1'">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
<body>
  <div class="profileimg">
    <img src=<?php echo $file; ?>  width="125" height="125">
  </div>
  <div class="profilename">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 130px; color: white; font-size: 30px;"><?php echo $username ?></p>
  </div>
    <div class="biotext">
        <textarea style="position: absolute;    top: 75px; left: 132.5px; width: 450px; height: 87px;"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
<div class="status">Currently logged in as <?php echo $username ?></div>
</footer>
</html>
```

The Display Profile Page (profile.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: login.php');
    }

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: login.php");
    }
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$file = "extra/" . $username . ".png";
if (!file_exists($file))
    $file = 'extra/defaultProfile.png';
?>
<html>
<title> Home Page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
          <li><a href="chat.php">Chat</a></li>
          <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
          <li class="logout"><a href="index.php?logout='1'">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
<body>
  <div class="profileimg">
    <img src=<?php echo $file; ?>  width="125" height="125">
  </div>
  <div class="profilename">
    <p style="position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 130px; color: white; font-size: 30px;"><?php echo $username ?></p>
  </div>
    <div class="biotext">
        <iframe width=25% height=9.5% src="getbio.php" background-color='white' style=" position: absolute; top: 75px; left: 132.5px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <p><a href="editprofile.php" style="color: gray;">Edit Your Profile</a></p>
</body>
<footer>
<div class="status">Currently logged in as <?php echo $username ?></div>
</footer>
</html>
```

The Part to get the bio text from a file (getbio.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: login.php');
    }

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: login.php");
    }
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$bioFile = "bio/" . $username . ".txt";
if (!file_exists($bioFile))
    $bioFile = 'bio/defaultBio.txt';
?>
<style>body {background-color: #f1f1f1;}
</style><body><?php  echo nl2br( file_get_contents($bioFile) );
?></body>
```

CSS (main.css)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #55d6aa;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav li:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav li::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;

  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav li:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
.logout {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.status {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  color: green;
}
.download {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.download a{
    color: lime;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.download a:hover{
    color: green;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.download li {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 17.5px;
}
```

The CSS is just for good viewing of the website and the other parts are for reference. I'm not sure how to save the text from the `textarea` (part of the editprofile.php) to files inside a folder called `/bio`. If anyone can help me, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Use a html form maybe?

Answer (score 0):

What is missing from your code is a way to send the data entered on the edit page to the server for processing and saving. Obviously, you cannot open a file that has not been created.

The html element used to send data to a server is `<form>` which interacts with editing (input) elements such as `<textarea>`.

I suggest some learning on your part. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms) is one place to start.